# Ansible conditional omit filter with looped items

Tags: ansible, jinja2, docker-container

I am passing these values to module parameter `docker_container`

```
    volumes:
     - "/opt/projects/logs/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}:/logs"
     - "/opt/projects/config/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}/config:/config"

...
..
.

     with_items: "{{ exposedPorts }}"
```

However, second volume binding is conditional on `when: push_config | default(false) | bool`

Looking for something like :`"/opt/projects/config/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}/config:/config ---> when push_config is true  else default(omit)"`  I am struggling to handle `| default(omit)` when there are looped items involved.

I tried below, but its not adding the volume mount and throwing an error, even when `push_config` is passed as `true`.

```
  volumes:
     - "/apps/projects/logs/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}:/logs"
     - "{{ if  'push_config | default(false) | bool'  '/apps/projects/logs/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}/.configmap:/tibco/config' else default(omit)  }}"


"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`omit` is a placeholder to totally skip an entire module parameter definition.

A typical usage in your case would be:

```
volumes: "{{ my_volume_list | default(omit) }}"
```

It cannot be used to replace an empty element of a list like you are trying to do above. You need to calculate the list of volumes for each items ans pass that as a parameter. Try something like the  following (not tested, just to put you on track):

```
- name: Create my container
  vars:
    default_mount: ["/opt/projects/logs/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}:/logs"]
    additional_mount_def: "/opt/projects/config/{{ Appname }}-{{ item }}/config:/config"
    additional_mount: >-
      {{ push_config | default(false) | bool | ternary ([additional_mount_def], []) }}
    all_mount: "{{ default_mount + additional_mount }}"
  docker_container:
    #....#
    volumes: "{{ all_mount }}"
  with_items: "{{ exposedPorts }}"
```

Comment: About the exposed ports, I agree. We don't have orchestration in place yet, and its complicated with our service registration mechanism.

Comment: I have changed a little , and its working now, Updated the answer and accepted it. Thanks.